# Запрет на многократное нажатие кнопки

Tags: php, javascript, forms

Доброго времени суток !

Как после одного нажатия заблокировать кнопку формы ?

Гуглил, но все что нагуглил это костыли с большим количеством кода.

Есть варианты с лаконичным и понятным кодом ?

С js не знаком, пользовался только готовыми кодами.

---

#### UPD

Нашел вот такой код, но он прячет кнопку.

```
$('#sendApplySettingsButton').click(function(){
$(this).hide();
});
```

Пробовал её дезактивировать таким образом  `$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");`, дезактивация работает, а вот обработчик не запускается.

Почему обработчик не запускается ?

В форме у атрибута `action` обработчик не указан, так как код обработчика находится в одном файле с формой.

#### UPD #2

Дошел вот до такого кода:

```
function blockMultiButton()
{
    $('#sendApplySettingsButton').click(function(){
        document.querySelector('#sendApplySettingsButton').disabled = true;
    });
    return false;
}
```

В форме указываю `onsubmit="blockMultiButton()"`

---

Спасибо всем кто пытался помочь !

Comment: думаю стоит выбрать ответ и закрыть вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('#id').disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Ты не сможешь нажать второй раз!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    console.log('button is pressed, do some logic');
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="press once" />
```

Comment: Не работает, а вот когда `hide` все работает

Comment: данный пример может не выполнятся ТОЛЬКО при использовании jquery < 1.7.х или наличии сторонних ошибок, влияющих на поведение данной конструкции.

Answer (score 0):

Есть идея поставить проверку типа "Статус".

```
var clicked = false;
 $('#sendApplySettingsButton').click(function(){
     if(!clicked) {
         // DO
         clicked = true;
     }
 });
```